# Print the output if the first column of three file match

Tags: bash, awk

I'm having 3 files with data as below:

**File1-**

```
a 10
b 20
c 30
```

**File2-**

```
a 11
b 22
c 45
d 33
```

**File3-**

```
a 23
b 33
c 46
```

I need to print the output like below if the first column of the three files matches:

```
a 10 11 23
b 20 22 33
c 30 45 46
```

I tried the below code but not getting the required output:

```
#!/bin/bash
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$2;next} {print $0,$1 in a?a[$1]:""}' File1 File2 File3
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With your shown samples, could you please try following. Written and tested with GNU `awk`.

```
awk '
{
  arr[$1]=(arr[$1]?arr[$1] OFS:"")$2
  count[$1]++
}
END{
  for(key in arr){
    if(count[key]==(ARGC-1)){
      print key,arr[key]
    }
  }
}
'  Input_file1  Input_file2  Input_file3
```

***NOTE:*** Just want to add here this answer to a new answer from all mentioned answers in shared dupe link under comments of question.

With shown samples output will be as follows.

```
a 10 11 23
b 20 22 33
c 30 45 46
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                                 ##Starting awk program from here.
{
  arr[$1]=(arr[$1]?arr[$1] OFS:"")$2  ##Creating arr with index of first field and value is 2nd field and keep appending its value in array.
  count[$1]++                         ##Creating count array with index of 1st field and keep increasing it.
}
END{                                  ##Starting END block of this program from here.
  for(key in arr){                    ##Traversing through all items in arr.
    if(count[key]==(ARGC-1)){         ##Checking condition if count with index of key is equal to ARGC-1 then print current item with its value.
      print key,arr[key]
    }
  }
}
' file1 file2 file3                   ##Mentioning Input_file names here.
```

Comment: Thanks ravinder the code is working fine and required output is generated. Can you please explain the code.

Comment: @Rama, let me add the explanation in few mins or so.

Comment: @Rama, Added detailed explanation now in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Using join:

```
join <(join File1 File2) File3
```

Join works with two files and so redirect the result of "join file1 and file2" back into another join command that compares this to file3