# Insert linebreak in a file after a string

Tags: perl, sed

I have a unique (to me) situation:
I have a file - `file.txt` with the following data:

```
"Line1", "Line2", "Line3", "Line4"
```

I want to insert a linebreak each time the pattern `",`  is found.
The output of `file.txt` shall look like:

```
"Line1", 
"Line2", 
"Line3", 
"Line4"
```

I am having a tough time trying to escape `",` .
I tried `sed -i -e "s/\",/\n/g" file.txt`, but I am not getting the desired result.

I am looking for a one liner using either `perl` or `sed`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use this `gnu sed`:

```sh
sed -E 's/(",)[[:blank:]]*/\1\n/g' file.txt

"Line1",
"Line2",
"Line3",
"Line4"
```

Note how you can use single quote in `sed` command to avoid unnecessary escaping.

If you don't have `gnu sed` then here is a POSIX compliant `sed` solution:

```sh
sed -E 's/(",)[[:blank:]]*/\1\
/g' file.txt
```

---

To save changes inline use:

```sh
sed -i.bak -E 's/(",)[[:blank:]]*/\1\
/g' file.txt
```

Comment: Both the commands work on RHEL 7.9+. But when I run the same command on my Mac running BigSur, the command doesnt update the file, just displays the output on screen

Comment: Check updated answer to save changes inline on Mac. btw I am also testing on mac

Comment: @anubhava, Hello sir can you please vote to reopen post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65901773/print-the-output-if-the-first-column-of-three-file-match not sure why it was deleted.

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following. using `awk`'s substitution mechanism here, in case you are ok with `awk`.

```
awk -v s1="\"" -v s2="," '{gsub(/",[[:blank:]]+"/,s1 s2 ORS s1)} 1' Input_file
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a Perl solution:

```
perl -pe 's/",\K/\n/g' file.txt
```

The substitution pattern matches the `",`, but the `\K` says to ignore anything to the left for the replacement (so, `",`) will not be replaced. The replacement then effectively inserts the newline.

I used the single quote for the argument to `-e`, but that doesn't work on Windows where you have to use `"`. Instead of escaping the `"`, you can specify it in another way. That's code number 0x22, so you can write:

```
perl -pe "s/\x22,\K/\n/g" file.txt
```

Or in octal:

```
perl -pe "s/\042,\K/\n/g" file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this Perl one-liner:

```
perl -F'/"\K,\s*/' -lane 'print join ",\n", @F;' in_file > out_file
```

Or this for in-line replacement:

```
perl -i.bak -F'/"\K,\s*/' -lane 'print join ",\n", @F;' in_file
```

The Perl one-liner uses these command line flags:
`-e` : Tells Perl to look for code in-line, instead of in a file.
`-n` : Loop over the input one line at a time, assigning it to `$_` by default.
`-l` : Strip the input line separator (`"\n"` on *NIX by default) before executing the code in-line, and append it when printing.
`-a` : Split `$_` into array `@F` on whitespace or on the regex specified in `-F` option.
`-F'/"\K,\s*/'` : Split into `@F` on a double quote, followed by comma, followed by 0 or more whitespace characters, rather than on whitespace. `\K` : Cause the regex engine to "keep" everything it had matched prior to the `\K` and not include it in the match. This causes to keep the double quote in `@F` elements, while comma and whitespace are removed during the split.
`-i.bak` : Edit input files in-place (overwrite the input file). Before overwriting, save a backup copy of the original file by appending to its name the extension `.bak`.

**SEE ALSO:**
[`perldoc perlrun`: how to execute the Perl interpreter: command line switches](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches)
[`perldoc perlrequick`: Perl regular expressions quick start](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrequick)

Comment: @briandfoy Thank you for the suggestion to take into account the double quote. Updated the answer.